# In Cloud Foundry, how do I create a service to run my Apache web server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, cloud-foundry, cf-cli

I'm on Ubuntu 18, running the following version of Cloud Foundry ...

```
$ cf -v
cf version 7.4.0+e55633fed.2021-11-15
```

I would to set up several containers, running off Docker image.  First is an Apache web server.  I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./my-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
COPY ./directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/directory
```

How do I set this up in Cloud foundry?  I tried creating a service but got these errors

```
$ cf cups apache-service -p "localhost, 80"
FAILED
No API endpoint set. Use 'cf login' or 'cf api' to target an endpoint.
```

When I tried to create this API endpoint I got

```
$ cf api "http://my_ip_address"
Setting API endpoint to http://my_ip_address...
Request error: Get "http://my_ip_address": dial tcp my_ip_address:80: connect: connection refused
TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
```

I'm thinking I'm missing something rather substantial but don't know what the right questions to ask are.

Comment: As an application developer, your primary workflow will be `cf push`. That takes your app and say "run it on CF". You can use this with Docker containers, if your Ops team allows that. The `-o` flag lets you `cf push` and registry URL. Services on CF are almost always for persistent state (databases, file storage, etc...). The user-provided service is for providing credentials to a service that's outside of the marketplace, like if you run your own DB or get a DB from an outside service provider.

Comment: See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/push-docker.html for more about pushing Docker images.

Comment: I'm actually trying to set this up as an admin on a test server we have.  So I wanted to create a space where the Docker image could be pushed to (I picked Apache for simplicity, but eventually it will be a Python image as well)

Comment: Then you just need to `cf push -o <image> <app-name>` your image. You can check `cf feature-flags` to make sure that Docker is enabled. If it's not, you as an admin can `cf enable-feature-flag diego_docker` to enable it.

Comment: But that command is for a developer to run to push up to an existing instance, no?  I want to create the instance to house all the images to be run.  Anyway, I tried your command on my server ("cf push -o apache chicommons") and got the error "No API endpoint set. Use 'cf login' or 'cf api' to target an endpoint."

Comment: Correct, if you have an image. You push the image to deploy it to CF. CF will pull the image directly from your image registry (Docker Hub, Harbor, etc..). Running a registry on CF would not be advised as that would require persistent storage and while you could add persistent storage with a volume service, volume services (SMB/NFS) are not idea for storing images. Beyond that, I'm sorry but I'm not following what you're trying to do. You'll have to try and explain more.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are providing (`dial tcp my_ip_address:80: connect: connection refused` ) is related to the `cf api $address` not responding.

Ensure that your Cloud Foundry API Endpoint is still active and you don't have any firewall preventing you from accessing the API. (port is open, the process is running, and the firewall is allowing traffic from your IP if applicable)

Comment: "Cloud Foundry API Endpoint is still active" is the heart of my question -- I want to create that endpoint based off an Apache Docker image.  How do I do that?

Comment: You can pass it through environment variables